# How to merge two data frames based on two variables?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames:

```
year  month   value1   value2
1925    1       34       45
1925    2       56       43
....
```

and

```
year  month   value1   value2
1925    1       NA       NA
1925    2       NA       NA
....
```

I want to fill in the second data frame with values from the first data frame. For instance, if a row in the second data frame is year = 1925 and month = 2, then it will fill in value1 and value2 for the NA values.

Comment: `merge(dat2[1:2], dat1)`

Comment: `coalesce(dat1, dat2)` from `dplyr` should work.